# How to add nodes to a WPF treeview (which method is better)?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

So I was reading a tutorial ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx)) that said that you should bind the treeview to some data, instead of just adding the nodes to the tree manually:

```
        TNode item = new TNode("1");
        item.Header = "node1";
        item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        tv_master.Items.Add(item);

        TNode item2 = new TNode("2");
        item2.Header = "node2";
        item2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        item.Items.Add(item2);
```

So is this right? or does it really not matter at all?

If I should be binding the treeview data, could you point me in the direction of a VERY simple tutorial? I have never done anything like this (databinding etc), and found it really tough to follow the above tutorial.

thanks!

Comment: See the [data bindng overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) if you are new to databinding.

Answer (score 2):

What you have found is a very good tutorial and thats exactly how it should be done. [Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2009/06/04/hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-treeview.aspx) is a simpler one.

> So is this right? or does it really not matter at all?

No, in WPF world its a crime. `DataBinding` is one of the core features of WPF and I strongly recommend you to read about it. Always databind do not manually loop and add grid rows or tree nodes, let the framework do it for you.

Comment: Ok, I will try using databinding, and have a read over the link you gave me :) thanks!